# Download salinity data from Government of Canada

Tags: data, download, canada

Since I would like to use the salinity data with lat/lon in the Gulf of St. Lawrence, Canada to compare with the fishing data. I'm trying to download the 2010-2019 average salinity data. As the table in this database and also the picture showed. (https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgisp.dfo-mpo.gc.ca%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FFGP%2FTeleost_BottomTemperatureSalinityFond%2FMapServer&source=sd)
[image]

And here is the open data portal. https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/10987662-c496-4ba8-a6b9-21cb5a134da2

Since my analysis requirement (I'll use R software), I want to download the data and mix it with my catch data under respective lat/lon. But I can't find how to get the raw data table in excel/csv format.